# posts_per_page displays only 2 posts instead of 4 posts

Tags: php, posts, wp-query, functions

I have a `wordpress/php` code as shown below in which I am trying to pull latest 4 channels at Line A in the code below.

```
function get_latest_channels( $instance_id = false ) {
    echo $instance_id;
    echo "<br>";
    if ( ! $instance_id ) {
        $query_args = array(
                'post_type'      => 'hello-channels',
                'ep_integrate'   => true,
                'posts_per_page' => 4,
        );
    } else {
        $query_args = array(
                'post_type'      => 'hello-channels',
                'ep_integrate'   => true,
                'meta_key'       => 'instance_id',
                'meta_value'     => $instance_id,
                'posts_per_page' => 4,
        );
    }
    $channels = new \WP_Query( $query_args );
    if ( $channels->have_posts() ) {
        $rtn = $channels->posts;
    }

    return $rtn;
}

$instance_id = 49;
$latest_channels = HELLO\Channels\get_latest_channels($instance_id);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($latest_channels); echo "</pre>". // Line A
```

The value of `$instance_id` is 49. On using 49 value, it should pull `4 latest channels`.

**Problem Statement:**

My code is working fine `dev/staging server` (meaning its pulling latest 4 channels at Line A) but in production server its pulling only 2 channels.

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the php code above so that it pulls latest 4 channels in the production server.

If I comment this line `'posts_per_page' => 4,` in the else section of the `function get_latest_channels( $instance_id = false )` then `Line A` is pulling `30 posts` in dev server.

Comment: I don't see where `$program_id` is defined in `get_latest_channels()`. And in the production server, do you actually have more than 2 "channels" with the metadata `instance_id`? Try `echo $channels->found_posts;`.

Comment: I have updated my question. On doing `echo $channels->found_posts;`, I am getting **1920** Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Again, the issue is only in production server. Dev/Staging server seems to work perfectly fine.

Comment: Do they share the same setup - data (settings, content, etc.), plugins and active theme? Have you tried with `return get_posts( $query_args );` - got same results?